# How to draw a parenthesis-like shape?

Tags: plotting, graphics, drawing

Can't quite figure out how to draw the shape below with Lines and make them play nice at the vertices where they meet. I currently have three lines of different thicknesses, but it's clearly not working.

Any suggestions on how make it work so in a way that survives changes in range, resolution, etc?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this using rectangles instead of Lines?

```
paren[t1_, t2_, p_, h_] := {Rectangle[{0, 0}, {t1, h}], 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {t2 + p, t2}], Rectangle[{0, h}, {t2 + p, h - t2}]}
Manipulate[
 Graphics[paren[t1, t2, p, h], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
 {{t1, .1}, 0, .3}, {{t2, .1}, 0, .3}, {{p, .2}, 0, .5}, {{h, 1}, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image: bracket anim]

Comment: Good idea, but I want horizontal lines to be thinner than vertical lines

Comment: @Wynne you can definitely add that parameter to what is in this answer. Give it a shot yourself.

Comment: @Wynne I added a second param.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your favorite font:

```
Manipulate[Style["[", FontSize -> t, FontFamily -> "Al Bayan"], {t, 1, 500}]
```

[image]